# Can Keras LSTM layer automatically convert 2D arrays?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

My model sort of looks like this:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(64, input_shape=(None, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=False))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(6))
```

And I feed in the input with shape (10000, 30). Everything was fine on my work laptop, which used Python of version 3.9. Later I go home and use my personal laptop to run the same program, which uses Python of version 3.7, I got an error like `expected to have 3 dimensions, but got array with (10000, 30)`. I have to modify the network to be:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(64, input_shape=(6, 5), return_sequences=True)
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=False)
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(6))
```

and reshape my input to be the shape of (10000, 6, 5). I wonder why this happened? Is it because the new version of Keras can automatically convert the input shape?

Some people don't believe the first input works. Below is a minimal reproducible example. Take a try!

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(64, input_shape=(None, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=False))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(6))
train_seq = np.array([i for i in range(100)]).reshape(10, 10)
valid_seq = np.array([i for i in range(60)]).reshape(10, 6)
model.compile(loss="mse",optimizer='adam')
model.fit(
    train_seq,
    valid_seq,
    epochs=3)
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZvTc.png)

Comment: No, Keras does not do any conversions, your first example would not work given the input shape you provided.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Don't be so arrogant before you try it. I wouldn't have asked if it doesn't work. Did you really try before you give me a negative? See the reproducible example I just added.

Answer (score 0):

I think TensorFlow of version 2.X backend Keras will convert your LSTM layer input to be `data[:, :, np.newaxis]` if your data is in 2D shape. I don't find any documentation about this, it's just inference based on my experience.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).